# Java Memory Leak in HTTP requests

Tags: java, memory-leaks, urlconnection

I have a Java application that is runs constantly. This application makes HTTP requests to a cloud server. The problem is that at each request the memory consumption increases until it reaches the point that the machine complete freezes. I isolated parts of the code and I'm sure the problem is with this code block making this http requests. Analyzing the JVM numbers, via prometheus / Grafana, I see that the use of non-heap memory (codecache and metaspace) are constantly increasing, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC5V1.png)

In the image above, whenever there is a drop in the line, it is when 98% of memory consumption reached, and Monit kills the app.

The method that is causing this memory consumption, is below (it is executed approx. 300 times until it exhausts a little more than 1.5GB of available memory in the initialization).

```
public AbstractRestReponse send(RestRequest request){
        BufferedReader in = null;
        OutputStream fout = null;
        URLConnection conn = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            MultipartEntityBuilder mb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();// org.apache.http.entity.mime
            for (String key : request.getParams().keySet()) {
                String value = (String) request.getParams().get(key);
//                System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
                mb.addTextBody(key, value);
            }
            
            if (request.getFile() != null) {
                mb.addBinaryBody("file", request.getFile());
            }
            org.apache.http.HttpEntity e = mb.build();
    
            conn = new URL(request.getUrl()).openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.addRequestProperty(e.getContentType().getName(), e.getContentType().getValue());// header "Content-Type"...
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(e.getContentLength()));
            fout = conn.getOutputStream();
            e.writeTo(fout);// write multi part data...
            
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            String text = result.toString(); 
            return objectMapper.readValue(text, FacialApiResult.class);
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally {
            try {
                inputStreamReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn.getInputStream().close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((HttpURLConnection)conn).disconnect()` comes to mind. Also String concatenation is time *and* memory exhaustive. And there was a minor bug in dropping newlines.

NullPointerExceptions may arise in the `finally` block when an open was not reached due to an exception. But you should have checked that.

```
public AbstractRestReponse send(RestRequest request) {
    URLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        MultipartEntityBuilder mb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();// org.apache.http.entity.mime
        for (String key : request.getParams().keySet()) {
            String value = (String) request.getParams().get(key);
            mb.addTextBody(key, value);
        }

        if (request.getFile() != null) {
            mb.addBinaryBody("file", request.getFile());
        }
        org.apache.http.HttpEntity e = mb.build();

        conn = new URL(request.getUrl()).openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.addRequestProperty(e.getContentType().getName(), e.getContentType().getValue());// header "Content-Type"...
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(e.getContentLength()));
        try (fout = conn.getOutputStream()){
            e.writeTo(fout);// write multi part data...
        }
        
        StringBuilder resullt = new StringBuilder(2048);
        try (BufferedReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) { // Charset
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line).append('\n'); // Newline
            }
        }
        String text = result.toString();
        return objectMapper.readValue(text, FacialApiResult.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                    ((HttpURLConnection) conn).disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //Better logger
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

- I explicitly defined the charset (UTF-8 might be wrong) - momentarily it is the server's default.
- Used a StringBuilder, and added the missing newline, which might have lead to wrong parsing.
- Try-with-resources for auto-closing, and a bit earlier. Hopefully this does not break anything.
- Disconnecting the connection when it is an HttpURLConnection. Mind the instanceof which might play a role in unit tests mocking.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have handled all possible closing part in the finally block. Anyway it's better to use try-with resources to safely close all Closeable objects, if your application is running on Java 7+. That may isolate the problem further if it doesn't fix.